# Cabal install failure on existing sandbox in Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I have installed the Haskell-platform on Windows. I am trying to build an existing project from an existing cabal sandbox. Whenever I attempt to reinstall, all packages fail with the following error:

```
cabal.exe: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix:
```

Was wondering where I need to specify an absolute directoy. Cabal is installed here:
Note: I am using `Powershell` to execute these commands.

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin\cabal.exe
```

Here's the full output.

```
websockets-snap-0.8.2.1 (new package)
Project-0.1 (new package)
cabal.exe: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0
cgi-3001.1.7.5
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
PS C:\Users\user\Project> cabal install --force-reinstalls
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0
cgi-3001.1.7.5
Continuing even though the plan contains dangerous reinstalls.
Configuring Crypto-4.2.5.1...
cabal.exe: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix:
/Users/user/Project/.cabal-sandbox
Failed to install Crypto-4.2.5.1
Configuring MonadRandom-0.1.13...
cabal.exe: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix:
/Users/user/Project/.cabal-sandbox
Failed to install MonadRandom-0.1.13
Configuring SHA-1.6.1...
cabal.exe: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix:
/Users/user/Project/.cabal-sandbox
Failed to install SHA-1.6.1
```

How do I specify an absolute directory name for prefix?

Comment: It looks like using `powershell` was my problem. Upon executing the same command in a standard windows prompt the prefix errors seem to have gone away.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the solution described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/05/22/cmd-exe-compatibility.aspx). It's basically about removing/replacing powershells default dir alias. But that's for sure not the most powershell-compatible way of fixing it.